# Combining parallel quicksort and parallel merge sort using Threading Building Blocks

Tags: performance, sorting, quicksort, mergesort, tbb

Can you combine parallel quicksort and parallel mergesort in order to achieve a better performance using TBB (Threading Building Blocks). And how would you do it?

Both quicksort and mergesort uses the divide-and-conquer algorithm. In parallel quicksort, the array can be divided recursively into 2 subsorts. The subsorts can be done in parallel.

However, i am not quite sure how the subsorts are merged and i was thinking if is it possible to gain better performance by using the merge step from mergesort (since it can be done in parallel) in the parallel quicksort algorithm and how would it be done if possible?

Comment: You are asking for opinions.  We don't do those here.  Sorry.

Comment: Asking about whether you can achieve a better performance by combining the 2 algorithms is not a opinion question. And I dont know whether you read how to do it, but its a normal question, i am not asking for anyones opinion

Comment: I'm not sure about TBB parallel implementation, but for a multi-threaded sort, on k cores, you can split an array into k parts, each part being n/k in size (except last might be slightly different), then each thread sorts (any method) one of the k parts, and then the k parts are merged. The merging could also be multi threaded. For k = 4, you could have two thread merge two sub-arrays each, then a single thread do the final merge.

Comment: quicksort is a partition sort, not a merging sort, hence parallel merging has no applicability to quicksort.  Parallel partitioning is possible via parallel scan, but it's been a performance-losing proposition in my experience.  See http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/quicksort-partition-via-prefix-scan/240003109 for how to do it.